# Adding external js script to next js

Tags: next.js

In my next project I need to add some script external js files.
Like so:

```
<script src="assets/js/productFactory.js"></script>
```

I saw one post that said to use Next/Head but this would be contrary to usual practice since many js files get loaded at the bottom of the page.

I tried including it as an import in _app.js like so:

```
import '../public/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js';
```

But this gave me an error.

Any ideas how I should do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `_document.js`, add script below `<NextScript />` tag

```
<body>
   <Main />
   <NextScript />
   <script src="assets/js/productFactory.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "useEffect" to achieve this.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const script = document.createElement('script');
        
   script.src = "https://script.js";
   script.async = true;
    
   document.body.appendChild(script);
    
   return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
   }
}, []);
```